# React testing library can't find imported component after state is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest

I have a form built with formik and yup. When the form is submitted if the email is left blank a modal is shown based on the component state `isWarning`. When I test it, I click on the button to submit the form without the email and I'm expecting to see some text from the modal but the test fail because it can't find the element.

Form:

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react"
import {
    TextField,
    Divider,
    Chip,
    Button,
    useMediaQuery,
    useTheme,
} from "@mui/material"
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next"
import { object, string, number } from "yup"
import { useFormik } from "formik"
import { useApplication } from "../../framework/useApplication"
import { Container, Outer, Inner } from "./styles"
import WarningDialog from "./WarningDialog"

const UserPreferences = () => {
    const { user } = useApplication()
    const { t } = useTranslation()
    const [isWarning, setIsWarning] = React.useState(false)
    const theme = useTheme()
    const fullScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"))

    const validationSchema = useMemo(
        () =>
            object({
                title: string(),
                firstName: string(),
                lastName: string(),
                email: string().email("Please enter a valid email"),
                jobTitle: string(),
                personalPhone: number().typeError(
                    "Please enter a valid number",
                ),
                mobilePhone: number().typeError("Please enter a valid number"),
            }),
        [t],
    )

    const handleSubmit = values => {
        if (values.email === "") {
            setIsWarning(true)
        } else {
            submitForm(values)
            setIsWarning(false)
        }
    }

    const submitForm = values => {
        console.log(values)
        setIsWarning(false)
    }

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            title: "",
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
            jobTitle: "",
            personalPhone: "",
            mobilePhone: "",
        },
        validationSchema: validationSchema,
        onSubmit: values => {
            handleSubmit({
                title: values.title,
                firstName: values.firstName,
                lastName: values.lastName,
                email: values.email,
                jobTitle: values.jobTitle,
                personalPhone: values.personalPhone,
                mobilePhone: values.mobilePhone,
            })
        },
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Divider>
                    <Chip label={`${t("common.details")}`} />
                </Divider>
                <Outer>
                    <span>User Name: {user.uname}</span>
                    <span>User ID: {user.userId}</span>
                </Outer>
                <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                    <Outer>
                        <Inner>
                            <TextField
                                id="title"
                                name="title"
                                label="title"
                                value={formik.values.title}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                placeholder="Title"
                                error={
                                    formik.touched.title &&
                                    Boolean(formik.errors.title)
                                }
                                helperText={
                                    formik.touched.title && formik.errors.title
                                }
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id="firstName"
                                name="firstName"
                                label="first name"
                                value={formik.values.firstName}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                placeholder="First Name"
                                error={
                                    formik.touched.firstName &&
                                    Boolean(formik.errors.firstName)
                                }
                                helperText={
                                    formik.touched.firstName &&
                                    formik.errors.firstName
                                }
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id="lastName"
                                name="lastName"
                                label="last name"
                                value={formik.values.lastName}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                placeholder="Last Name"
                                error={
                                    formik.touched.lastName &&
                                    Boolean(formik.errors.lastName)
                                }
                                helperText={
                                    formik.touched.lastName &&
                                    formik.errors.lastName
                                }
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id="email"
                                name="email"
                                label="email"
                                value={formik.values.email}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                placeholder="Email"
                                error={
                                    formik.touched.email &&
                                    Boolean(formik.errors.email)
                                }
                                helperText={
                                    formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email
                                }
                            />
                        </Inner>
                        <Inner>
                            <TextField
                                id="jobTitle"
                                name="jobTitle"
                                label="job title"
                                value={formik.values.jobTitle}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                placeholder="Job Title"
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id="personalPhone"
                                name="personalPhone"
                                label="personal phone"
                                value={formik.values.personalPhone}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                placeholder="Personal Phone"
                                error={
                                    formik.touched.personalPhone &&
                                    Boolean(formik.errors.personalPhone)
                                }
                                helperText={
                                    formik.touched.personalPhone &&
                                    formik.errors.personalPhone
                                }
                            />
                            <TextField
                                id="mobilePhone"
                                name="mobilePhone"
                                label="mobile phone"
                                value={formik.values.mobilePhone}
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                placeholder="Mobile Phone"
                                error={
                                    formik.touched.mobilePhone &&
                                    Boolean(formik.errors.mobilePhone)
                                }
                                helperText={
                                    formik.touched.mobilePhone &&
                                    formik.errors.mobilePhone
                                }
                            />
                        </Inner>
                    </Outer>
                    <Outer>
                        <Button type="submit">{t("common.save")}</Button>
                    </Outer>
                </form>
            </Container>
            {isWarning && (
                <WarningDialog
                    handleClose={() => setIsWarning(false)}
                    handleSubmit={() => submitForm(formik.values)}
                    open={isWarning}
                    fullScreen={fullScreen}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserPreferences
```

Test:

```
import React from "react"
import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react"
import UserPreferences from "./UserPreferences"
import { vi } from "vitest"

vi.mock("../../framework/useApplication", () => ({
    useApplication: () => ({ user: { uname: "testUser", userId: "123" } }),
}))

vi.mock("useTranslation", () => ({
    useTranslation: () => ({ t: vi.fn() }),
}))

vi.mock("./WarningDialog", () => {
    return {
        default: () => <div>Email field is blank</div>,
    }
})

vi.mock("formik", () => ({
    useFormik: () => ({
        values: {
            title: "",
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
            jobTitle: "",
            personalPhone: "",
            mobilePhone: "",
        },
        errors: {},
        touched: {},
        handleChange: vi.fn(),
        handleSubmit: vi.fn(),
    }),
}))

describe("UserPreferences", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        vi.clearAllMocks()
    })

    test("displays warning dialog when submitting with empty email", async () => {
        render(<UserPreferences />)

        const submitButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /save/i })

        // Submit form with empty email
        fireEvent.click(submitButton)

        // Verify warning dialog is displayed
        expect(
            await screen.findByText("Email field is blank"),
        ).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
})
```

Error:
`TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Email field is blank.`

Comment: Try wrapping it in a <p> tag - RTL is quite strict on using semantic elements.

Comment: @Muskett it didn't work :(